# how to cache static html elements in a web page?

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to know how to configure a website to cache static elements of html pages?

I have heard this is automatically done by the browser/server but thinking is it a good practice to use meta tags to do the caching

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: Elements are not cached. Documents are. The examples you give suggest that you would want to *prevent* caching without knowing how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta cache control tag allows Web publishers to define how pages should be handled by caches. 
They include directives to declare what should be cacheable, what may be stored by caches, modifications of the expiration mechanism, and revalidation and 
reload controls.

The allowed values are:

**Public** - may be cached in public shared caches

**Private** - may only be cached in private cache

**no-Cache** - may not be cached

**no-Store** - may be cached but not archived